# Gradle Spring Boot Rest Service Application Deployment in Azure

Tags: java, azure, github, spring-boot, gradle

I have been working on SpringBoot with Gradle tool. I am able to deploy the application locally. When I am trying to deploy using Microsoft Azure through GitHub the application got deployed. But I am not able to trigger the application services.

It means when I am trying to hit my REST service or Swagger page which is in application I am getting 404 error message on browser. I was able deploy the same using Heroku.

Note: I am new to Microsoft Azure. I have followed few Stack Overflow pages and Azure videos and Documents. But none of them were very helpful.

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pls read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you post the details for deploying your spring boot app as an executable jar or a war file?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there are two ways for packaging a spring boot application, as an executable jar or a war file. I don't know which one is your choice.

If you packaged as an executable jar to deploy it on Azure WebApp, you need to create a `web.xml` file at the path `wwwroot`, and follow the document [`Upload a custom Java web app to Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload) to configure it. The key configuration is for the attribute `processPath` with the value like `java -jar <your spring boot executable jar file name>.jar`.

If you packaged as a war file to deploy it on Azure WebApp, it's simple that you just need to refer to the document [`Add a Java application to Azure App Service Web Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-add-app) to upload the war file to the related directory `webapps`. However, if you didn't configure Azure WebApp with Java runtime, you also need to configure your Azure webapp instance on Azure portal or create a `web.xml` file to configure it as below.

Hope it helps.